# is there a way to overcome the ConcurrentModificaionError in the following code, or a better implimentation

Tags: java, iterator

What I want to do is make a sorting function that uses iterator over an ArrayList. I want to traverse the array in reverse, check the smaller of i-th and (i-1)-th element, if i-th element is smaller I move it to the front of the array.

here's my go at the case:

```
import java.util.*;
// Other imports go here
// Do NOT change the class name
class Main
{
    public void cq1(ArrayList<Integer> list) { 
    ListIterator<Integer> l1=list.listIterator();
    ListIterator<Integer> l2=list.listIterator();
    while(l1.hasNext()){l1.next();l2.next();}//loop to send the listIterator to the end of ArrayList
    l1.previous();//make this iterator point to the second last element
  while(l1.hasPrevious()) 
  { 
      int a=l1.previous();
      int b=l2.previous();
    if (a < b) 
    {
      list.remove(l1.previousIndex()+1); 
      list.add(0, a); 
    } 
      System.out.println(list); 
  } 

}//fn
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main obj=new Main();
        int a[]={-4, 16, 9, 1, 64, 25, 36, 4, 49};
        ArrayList<Integer> oe = new ArrayList();
        for(int i :a)oe.add(i);
        obj.cq1(oe);
    }//main
    }//class
```

the problem is, that after the first iteration the exception:ConcurrentModificationError; pops up

I've also tried to do the same thing whilst going forward instead of backward same error pops up after the first iteration.

Comment: Try to perform your remove operation using the listIterator.remove method, instead of the list.remove method. List.remove generally throws a ConcurrentModificationException when removing an element while looping on it.

Comment: You do realise java has an [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method for collections and an [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) method for arrays right?. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Fabien I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: @RVISHAL yeah, I do and I use it all the time. But I wanted to try something new so I did. That's it. I don't think there's anything wrong with it.